# How to dynamically do a linear interpolation of data in a row with missing values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data

```
Date    Data
8/25/2017   980
8/24/2017   64
8/23/2017   593   
8/22/2017   595
8/21/2017   
8/20/2017   
8/19/2017   794
8/18/2017   437
8/17/2017   
8/16/2017   
8/15/2017   
8/14/2017   629
```

What if i wanted (794-595)/3 in cell 21st August and 2*(794-595)/3 in cell 22nd August and similarly (629-437)/4 in 17th August, 2*(629-437)/4 in 16th August etc...

How to do this dynamically without regard to the number of missing values in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below provides one solution, and the animated gif shows the code solving your problem.  Of course, there are many ways of solving this problem, but this is simple. At least this shows you what inputs will be needed. It assumes the x-values increment by 1 (as you have in your data).  Otherwise you'd need to use something like the slope & intercept functions.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub interpolate()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range
Set r = Application.InputBox("select interpolation range", , , Type:=8)
For Each cell In r
  If cell = "" Then
    cell = r(1) + (r(r.Rows.Count) - r(1)) * (cell.row - r.row) / (r(r.Rows.Count).row - r(1).row)
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this but you thought that those two blank space groups are the only ones there. The reality is, that I might have more blank spaces (4 blank space sequence, 5 blank space, 1 blank space etc) and I don't know how many of such sequences will be in the data. The solution required would be a dynamic solution that will interpolate data in each and every blank sequence, irrespective of the number of blanks. I don't want to restrict myself to the two blank sequences in the test data by manually doing it each for each sequence.

Comment: I tried to provide a solution to answer the original question, and acknowledge that it may not cover all the possibilities. But then again, the idea is just to get you going in a direction that allows you to solve your problem. Nevertheless, I believe the solution above would indeed handle "more blank spaces (4 blank space sequence, 5 blank space, 1 blank space etc)" and also "irrespective of the number of blanks". If you want it done automatically for all such sequences that could be done by starting from the top, stepping down to find each blank sequence, and then applying the formula I used

Comment: Is there no way to automatically do it? Some algorithm that goes through a column, finds all the blank sequences and fills in the blank spaces?

Comment: Basically find the blank spaces in a column then apply your formula. But it should be automatic.